# How can I get a specific map value from Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

How can I get a specific map value from Thymeleaf?

```
        <tr th:each="item : ${items}">
            <td th:each="element : ${item}">
                   <a th:text="${element['key']}">anchor</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

In the code above, all keys corresponding to an element are displayed.

But what I want is to get `element['projectName']`.
That is, I want it to be something like this:

```
        <tr th:each="item : ${items}">
            <td th:each="element : ${item}">
                   <a th:text="${element['key']}"
                        th:href="${element.get('projectName')}">anchor</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
```

The data type of items is `List<Map<String, Object>>`, and the values ​​in items are

```
        assertThat(innerItems.get(0).get("modelName")).isEqualTo("a");
        assertThat(innerItems.get(0).get("item")).isEqualTo(1);
        assertThat(innerItems.get(0).get("id")).isEqualTo("q");
        assertThat(innerItems.get(0).get("projectName")).isEqualTo("DefaultProject");
        assertThat(innerItems.get(0).get("user_poi_no")).isEqualTo(1);
is.
```

Comment: ${map.get(key)} , it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you loop over a map, you get a special `java.util.Map.Entry` element with a `key` and a `value`, not the actual item itself. In the example you gave, using `item` instead of `element` should work (if that is indeed what you want):

```
<tr th:each="item : ${items}">
  <td th:each="element : ${item}">
    <a th:text="${element['key']}" th:href="${item['projectName']}">anchor</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

If you just wanted the `projectName` from each item in your list, you don't even need the inner loop.  Like this for example:

```
<tr th:each="item : ${items}">
  <td>
    <a th:text="${item['projectName']}">anchor</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it would be better to loop by key in your inner loop if I get it right.

```html
    <tr th:each="item : ${items}">
        <td th:each="key: ${item.keySet()}">
              <a th:text="${key}" th:href="${item.get(key)}">anchor</a>
       </td>
    </tr>
```